# Windows exec runner fails to clone git repo

Tags: go, drone.io

I'm getting `Host key verification failed.` when trying to clone a repository through ssh protocol. In cmd and PS it clones it without any problem.

First I thought maybe it's the user, and I went and changed it on Computer Management -> Services -> drone-runner-exec to be run as local user not `SYSTEM` user. Same thing.

Then I went and ran drone-runner-exec.exe (btw it does not have `.exe` at the end when one downloads it) directly on cmd.exe; but same thing. Interestingly runner gives `msg="cannot accept stage" error="Optimistic Lock Error"` and on server output is: `Host key verification failed.` from git command.

Please help,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this problem, there is a workaround like this: specify in your `.drone.yml` file a environment variable like this:

```
clone:
  disable: true

steps:
- name: clone
  environment:
    HOME: C:\Users\username\
```

This will tell git command where ssh keys are.

Cheers